# I need to overwrite entirely or remove previous file for automated testing scripts

Tags: python-2.7

I am running automated tests for equipment at work for shipment. However, I currently have my scripts write into a .csv and continue where it left off. I would like the python script to either overwrite that text file entirely before re-writing (prefered method) or I would like to have my scripts delete the .csv file before creating a new one with the same name. So far, I am unable to do anything with my files because the tests do not conclude at the same length each time, so it is difficult to find the stopping point for data analysis even when I start writing to the file from the top. What is the best way to overwrite a text file entirely each time the script is run?

I am using the following:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('title stuff\n')
    loop i:
        fp.write(x[i])
```

What can I change before this to allow me to delete the filename before I create a new one with the same name?

Comment: "w" mode truncates the file so existing data is deleted every time you run it. Are multiple scripts trying to write this file concurrently?

Comment: I see my error, I had another script trying to write to this file concurrently. Thank you for the response, I got it figured out!